# Change nginx.conf file in docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, volume, docker-volume

I want to change `nginx.conf` file but its file made with `docker-compose.yml` file.
<br>Its file use from `alfg/nginx-rtmp` image. my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  rtmp:
    image: alfg/nginx-rtmp
    container_name: my_container
    ports:
      - '800:80'
      - '1935:1935'
    volumes:
      - ./conf/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I try to edit `nginx.conf` file and remove this lines:

```
hls_variant _720p2628kbs BANDWIDTH=2628000,RESOLUTION=1280x720;
hls_variant _480p1128kbs BANDWIDTH=1128000,RESOLUTION=854x480;
hls_variant _360p878kbs BANDWIDTH=878000,RESOLUTION=640x360;
hls_variant _240p528kbs BANDWIDTH=528000,RESOLUTION=426x240;
hls_variant _240p264kbs BANDWIDTH=264000,RESOLUTION=426x240;
```

But when system restarted, everything return to their place!
<br> Original `nginx.conf` file:

```
daemon off;

error_log /dev/stdout info;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4000;

        application stream {
            live on;

            exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/stream/$name
              -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -b:v 2500k -f flv -g 30 -r 30 -s 1280x720 -preset superfast -profile:v baseline rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name_720p2628kbs
              -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -f flv -g 30 -r 30 -s 854x480 -preset superfast -profile:v baseline rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name_480p1128kbs
              -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -b:v 750k -f flv -g 30 -r 30 -s 640x360 -preset superfast -profile:v baseline rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name_360p878kbs
              -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v libx264 -b:v 400k -f flv -g 30 -r 30 -s 426x240 -preset superfast -profile:v baseline rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name_240p528kbs
              -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 64k -c:v libx264 -b:v 200k -f flv -g 15 -r 15 -s 426x240 -preset superfast -profile:v baseline rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/$name_240p264kbs;
        }

        application hls {
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_fragment_naming system;
            hls_fragment 5;
            hls_playlist_length 10;
            hls_path /opt/data/hls;
            hls_nested on;

            hls_variant _720p2628kbs BANDWIDTH=2628000,RESOLUTION=1280x720;
            hls_variant _480p1128kbs BANDWIDTH=1128000,RESOLUTION=854x480;
            hls_variant _360p878kbs BANDWIDTH=878000,RESOLUTION=640x360;
            hls_variant _240p528kbs BANDWIDTH=528000,RESOLUTION=426x240;
            hls_variant _240p264kbs BANDWIDTH=264000,RESOLUTION=426x240;
        }
    }
}

http {
    root /www/static;
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    server_tokens off;
    access_log /dev/stdout combined;

    # Uncomment these lines to enable SSL.
    # ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    # ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    # ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    # ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    # ssl_session_timeout 1d;

    server {
        listen 80;

        # Uncomment these lines to enable SSL.
        # Update the ssl paths with your own certificate and private key.
            
        # listen 443 ssl;
        # ssl_certificate     /opt/certs/example.com.crt;
        # ssl_certificate_key /opt/certs/example.com.key;

        location /hls {
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }
            root /opt/data;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location /live {
          alias /opt/data/hls;
          types {
              application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
              video/mp2t ts;
          }
          add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
          add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        }

        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }

        location /stat.xsl {
            root /www/static;
        }

        location /crossdomain.xml {
            default_type text/xml;
            expires 24h;
        }
    }
}
```

I try to remove them myself with editor but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to `commit` the container (for backing up).

Next with `docker exec -u 0 <container name> /bin/sh` connect to shell and with `nano` change `nginx.conf.template` file